# Can I sort a table of content in a Google Drive Document

Tags: google-docs

I would very much like to be able to sort a generated TOC in a Google Document. The table of content is generated on heading basis.

Answer (score 1):

Once the TOC is generated, you can cut and paste each link into whatever order you would like. Any time the TOC is regenerated, however, it will reset any of your changes to match the structure of the document again.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think it would also be possible to copy them to a spreadsheet, sort and copy back. But it would be so much easier if there would be an index function that can be sorted or something.